# Extract nested expression with parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I need to write a parser that can extract all the text between two parentheses:

```
parser("left-text ( text-to-extract ) right-text") = "text-to-extract"
```

The `text-to-extract` may contain parentheses, while both `left-text` and `right-text` cannot.

I'm using Scala parser combinators, and I would like the solution to fit into it.
Can you help me?

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: Do you really need _only_ the middle text (i.e., you'll throw away the left and right text), or are you just trying to split the string into these three pieces?

Answer (score 1):

If left text is `{` and right text is `}` then your parser should be the following.

```
def parser: Parser[String] = "{" ~> "[^}]*".r <~ "}"
```

The trick is to use `~>` and `<~`instead of `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @jseteny 's answer, here is a full example, using Scala 2.13.9

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

class DemoParser extends RegexParsers {
  def removeBraces: Parser[String] = "{" ~> "[^}]*".r <~ "}"
}
object ExtractNested {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parser = new DemoParser
    val result = parser.parseAll(parser.removeBraces, "{text-to-extract}")
    println(result.get)
  }
}
```